# AJAX request works when domain name set to 127.0.01 but not an external address

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

This may be a difficult one to answer but I'll try to provide as much information as I can.

Windows Server 2003
PHP 5.3
Apache 2.2
jQuery

I have a portal at, for example, http://portal.someoutsidedomain.com which makes AJAX requests to check the progress of calculations it is solving, and then a further AJAX request when complete. If I add the domain name to my local hosts file giving it the IP address of 127.0.0.1 the AJAX requests complete fine and everything is displayed on page as it should. However when the IP address is not in the hosts file the server doesn't properly finish and the results are not displayed correctly. Oddly enough there is nothing on the server that connects externally for the calculations to work and in theory it should make no difference whatsoever.

Apache access log when not working

```
88.x.x.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:53:05 +0100] "POST /_ajax/progress_check HTTP/1.1" 200 5
88.x.x.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:53:05 +0100] "POST /_ajax/delete_progress HTTP/1.1" 200 1
88.x.x.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:49:15 +0100] "POST /_ajax/run_pricing HTTP/1.1" 200 515
```

Apache access log when working

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:42 +0100] "POST /_ajax/progress_check HTTP/1.1" 200 5
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:42 +0100] "POST /_ajax/delete_progress HTTP/1.1" 200 1
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:19:52 +0100] "POST /_ajax/run_pricing HTTP/1.1" 200 515
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/term_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 26626
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/prem_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 26945
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/age_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 19985
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/irr_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 32910
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/p_l_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 25960
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2014:18:23:43 +0100] "GET /images/charts/310/npv_graph_b05cde7.png HTTP/1.1" 200 30297
```

I have noticed that the initial run_pricing AJAX request doesn't seem to finish according to Firebug on the non-working attempt. I tried to get to the bottom of that by using the 'exit' function in PHP but something strange happens in that test. At the beginning of the code and at the start of a 'for loop' it exits as it should, however when I move the exit deeper into the for the 'for loop' it does not exit, the amount of loops it can complete before the exit function works also changes (520, 521 or 522) for no apparent reason. I would have said memory or execution time however PHP is set to use 2GB and the execution time is set to 600 seconds which is more than enough. I've spent 3 days trying to get to the bottom of this and cannot understand how a difference in IP makes the system work or not, I will try the router settings next but if anyone else has any other ideas they would be much appreciated.

Apache/Router Configuration

```
.com -> 88.x.x.1 -> 192.168.0.1
.com -> 127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1
```

I've added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my .htaccess however while monitoring the requests in Firebug it shows that the AJAX request to run_pricing sends back no response when the IP address is 88.x.x.1 unlike the initial and progress requests which displays the below.

```
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
```

This comes back to the problem of the code not exiting or returning all values, when putting the exit on loop attempt 523 (for example) the code goes past this as there are functions that are run which defies logic in my limited mind. I cannot explain how this all works perfectly when the domain IP is not external.

**Possible Fix**: By adding an SSL certificate to the domain it works, which must mean that there is some configuration error in the Apache config I presume? Anyone?

My standard configuration is, for all domains that do not require SSL I set up with the virtual host of *:80 and reserve the base IP to serve for those domains, all other domains have a dedicated IP for the SSL to work such as 192.168.0.1:80/443

```
ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/localhost"

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/localhost"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localdomain.local
    ServerName portal.someoutsidedomain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/portal.someoutsidedomain.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2/htdocs/portal.someoutsidedomain.com"
    ServerName portal.someoutsidedomain.com:443
    ServerAdmin postmaster@portal.someoutsidedomain.com
    ErrorLog "C:/Apache2/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/Apache2/logs/access.log"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/portal.someoutsidedomain.com.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/portal.someoutsidedomain.com.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Apache2/conf/certificates/portal.someoutsidedomain.com-ca.crt"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/Apache2/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "C:/Apache2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Many thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description if this is part of your issue, but are you aware of [same-origin restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) for Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions :

1) Have you tried jsonp type for your ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
     url:"yourdistantserverurl",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     complete:function(json){
         //do your job here
     },   
});
```

more information : http://json-p.org/

2) you can set your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in htaccess or virtualhost or using PHP header function to `*` to accept all requests from others domains.

For further informations search with keywords : ajax cross domain